# How to configure CSP with inline-style in Vue or Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, content-security-policy, unsafe-inline

I want to deploy a Nuxt application but I have a problem with Csp. I added all the Sha256 to my Csp but some lines are still stuck. I think it's the lines with :style="". What would be the solution? Is it really risky to add an "unsafe-inline"?

Everything works if I add "unsafe-inline" but I'm not sure that's great for site security.
I also specify that all my other Headers are well configured

Answer (score 0):

If you add hashes for event attributes such as onclick, onerror etc, it won't work. You can make it work if the browser has implemented full support for 'unsafe-hashes', but there are likely still a lot of users who are not at that level. Otherwise you'll need to rewrite the event attributes to event listeners if you don't want to add 'unsafe-inline'.